# STA for non created Thread/Task

Tags: c#, multithreading

I made a simple async method for a loading animation while code runs. The code which runs adds controls to stackpanel.

in Page_Loaded Event i just have:

```
Test();
```

In Test() i have

```
private async void Test()
{
   testbtn.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
   await Task.Run(() => LoadAll());
   testbtn.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

and in LoadAll() are DockPanels etc.
for exmaple:

```
DockPanel headerpanel = new DockPanel();
headerpanel.LastChildFill = false;
```

When Running this i get an error because the Thread isnt a STA Thread.
How can I make it STA even if i dont created a Thread. (just have `await Task.Run(() => LoadAll());`)

Do I have to create a big Thread etc. only for a simple animation bar while code runs?

Comment: Marking a thread as STA is a *promise*.  The kind of promise that a Task can never fulfill correctly.  Breaking the promise can have excessively nasty side-effects, likely to deadlock the finalizer thread for example.

Answer (score 2):

You can run your task in a scheduler that allows you to safely execute UI Code:

```
private async void Test()
{
    testbtn.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    TaskScheduler scheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
    await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => LoadAll(),
        CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, scheduler);
    testbtn.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Do I have to create a big Thread etc. only for a simple animation bar while code runs?

No; just don't do UI work on a background thread. Use `IProgress<T>`/`Progress<T>` instead, e.g.:

```
private async void Test()
{
  testbtn.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
  IProgress<string> progress = new Progress<string>(value => { ... });
  await Task.Run(() => LoadAll(progress));
  testbtn.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

and have `LoadAll` call `progress.Report("update")` when it wants to update the UI.